# Spring Data - Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, oop, intellij-idea

I'm currently learning about Spring Data and get this error when I try run my test. There's apparently nothing wrong from this, but I could not solve the problem even by looking at some answers here in Stack Overflow. I also tried to use @ImportResource annotation.

Here is my code.

Test case:

[image]

XML file configuration:

[image]

I'm not sure if this makes sense, but here is the project tree.

[image]

For this project I've been using Maven dependencies like, Postgresql, Spring Framework JPA and test, Junit and Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.
My reference https://www.baeldung.com/spring-junit-failed-to-load-applicationcontext

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:WEB-INF/spring-config.xml"})
```

Comment: I read this article and I tried these steps, but didn't work as well.
Thank you, anyway

Comment: Sorry about that, is your IDE intellij is paid version "Ultimate version" ? Because if its free version "Community version" it doest support spring. Reference https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce

Comment: I didn't even realize that. My IntelliJ is a free version "Community". Thank you SpicySandwich for your time.